# How to read single digits from a string and perform a function on them?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to gather user input in the form of a non negative integer. I then want to take this integer and tell the user how many odd, even, and zero, single digit numbers there are in their integer.

Ex. User inputs "123" and the program outputs Evens: 1 Odds: 2 Zeros: 0

Here is my code so far.

```
def main():
print("1. Enter a new number")
print("2. Print the number of odd, even and zero digits in the integer")
print("3. Print the sum of the digits of the integer")
print("4. Quit the program")

value = (input("Please enter a non-negative integer"))
Sum = 0
evens = 0
odds = 0
zeros = 0

loop=True

while loop:
    main()
    choice = int(input("Enter a number between 1 and 4:"))


    if choice==1:
        loop=False
        value = int(input("Please enter a non-negative integer"))
        loop=True

    elif choice==2:
        loop=False
        value_string = str(value)
        for ch in value_string:
            print(ch)
        for [1] in value:
            if i % 2 == 0:
                evens = evens + 1
                print(evens)

    elif choice==3:
        loop=False
        while (value >0):
            remainder = value % 10
            Sum = Sum + remainder
            value = value //10
        print("Sum of the digits = %d" %Sum)
```

Comment: `for [1] in value:` has quite a number of problems.

Comment: Please fix your indentation

Comment: put code again and use button `{}` to correctly format code on SO.

Comment: Sorry for the poor formatting, I think I have addressed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is badly indented and hard to follow. But you could do something like this.

```
value = input('enter digits ')
digits = [int(d) for d in value]
odds = sum(d % 2 for d in digits)
zeros = sum(d == 0 for d in digits)
evens = len(digits) - odds
print('evens: {}, odds: {}, zeros: {}'.format(evens, odds, zeros))
```

Comment: Than you sir! This solved my problem. I'm fairly new to coding so I apologize for my horrible indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I have your same code well indented, refactored and refined to handle some edge cases and to provide correct results.

```
def main():
    print("1. Enter a new number")
    print("2. Print the number of odd, even and zero digits in the integer")
    print("3. Print the sum of the digits of the integer")
    print("4. Quit the program")

loop = True

while loop:
    main()
    choice = str(input("Enter a number between 1 and 4: "))
    if (choice.isdigit() and 1 <= int(choice) <= 4):
        choice = int(choice)
        if choice == 1:
            value = str(input("Please enter a non-negative integer"))
            if (value.isdigit() and int(value) >= 0):
                value = int(value)
            else:
                print(
                    "You provided an invalid input. Please enter a non-negative number")
        elif choice == 2:
            value = str(value)
            odds = len([d for d in value if (int(d) % 2) == 1])
            evens = len([d for d in value if (int(d) % 2) == 0])
            zeros = len([d for d in value if d == '0'])
            print('odd: {} even: {} zeros: {}'.format(odds, evens, zeros))
        elif choice == 3:
            value = str(value)
            print('Sum of digits = {}'.format(sum(map(int, value))))
        elif choice == 4:
            print("Program is exiting")
            loop = False
    else:
        print("You provided an invalid input. Please enter a number between 1 and 4")
```